# Run Function When Element and not off screen

Tags: javascript, html

i'm using javascript to play a sound when a notification is visible, but the problem is, it plays before it slides into view, the notification starts off screen, then it slides into view, does anyone have a solution to this

I've tried a wait script but it either plays too late or too soon

I want the script to play when it slides into view, not too soon and not too late

Comment: Could you add a [mcve] to your question? Without any context it is very difficult to see what you are asking.

Comment: Oh sure, I'll do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is new API called Intersection Observer see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API.

By using it, you can determine when your element in visible in viewport.